# Should we count [reference-count] as a reference to [reference-counting]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I found that there are two very similar tags:

- [reference-counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-counting) (315×)
- [reference-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-count) (14×)

To me, [reference-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-count) is a synonym to [reference-counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-counting). Browsing the questions of [reference-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-count), I could not find one that would not fit [reference-counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-counting) as well.

Lacking to create synonyms myself, I propose to do this with this post.

Comment: [status-declined] as the OP already cleaned the tags and there is no need to action a synonym now. If further evidence suggests otherwise, please post a new request.